# Pakistani point of view on the Liberation War of Bangladesh

Tags: war, pakistan, bangladesh

Being a Bangladeshi, it has been difficult to know the Pakistani view of the Liberation War in 1971. What their exact goal was, how they intended to achieve this goal, what resources they had and how they justified the horrible atrocities that have been confirmed by the recent war tribunal in Bangladesh. Any resources, insights, links to pdf documents are welcome. This is for research purposes and I'm working on a deadline. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help if you noted where you've already looked, e.g. Wikipedia, etc.

Comment: Shame we can't hook you up with the person who asked [this question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/1800/why-did-the-the-east-pakistanis-oppose-urdu-as-their-national-language-while-ind) 7 years ago.

Comment: @T.E.D., https://www.quora.com/Why-is-Bangladesh-not-as-conservative-as-Pakistan/answers/202369358

Comment: @MCW Do personal interviews and encounters count?

Comment: @T.E.D., Do personal interviews and encounters count?